# I broke a working javascript script trying to expand it

Tags: javascript

The script below was working properly (toggling display on/off) before I added lines 3 to 8 to avoid displaying more than one element at a time (there are hundreds). It still works after adding lines 3 to 8 but it does not toggle back to "display:none;" (there is always one element visible).

I only have basic knowledge of Javascript and I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Can someone give me a hint/solution?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    numb = document.forms.length
    for(i=1;i<numb+1;i++) {
        j="N"+i
        elemnt = document.getElementById(j); 
        elemnt.style.display = "none";
    }
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'none')
        e.style.display = 'block';
    else
        e.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide at least a sample of the related markup? It may be just a matter of order. The loop will set all of the elements to hidden. And, only after that does the `if` test check for the selected element's visibility, which seems to have been hidden by the loop, and displays it.

Comment: Also, how do you determine the `id` value that is passed to the function.

Comment: What is passed in as the `id` argument when you want all elements to be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring i as local variable in for -loop.Instead use this.Also you have not declared `elemnt` variable.Hope you dont want it to be global variable

```
 for(var i=1;i<numb+1;i++) {
            j="N"+i
       elemnt = document.getElementById(j); 
       elemnt.style.display = "none";
           }
```

Comment: Though you're right about how `i` and `elemnt` SHOULD be declared, how would it actually fix the function? `i` still gets set to 1 before the first iteration of the loop, and `elemnt` still gets set to whatever element has the id from `j`.

Comment: for(var i=0;i<numb+1;i++).Also I dont understand the reason of i<numb+1

Comment: I would suspect that the element ID's start with one (`"N1"`) and not zero.

Comment: @user2181397 What I'm saying is whether OP uses `(i=1;i...)` or `(var i=1;i...)` there shouldn't be any difference on how this piece of code runs. Either way `i` is being set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring all the variables first:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var i, elemnt, state,
    numb = document.forms.length + 1;
  for( i = 1; i < numb; i++ ) {
    elemnt = document.getElementById( "N" + i );
    elemnt.style.display = "none";
  }
  elemnt = document.getElementById( id );
  state = elemnt.style.display === 'none';
  elemnt.style.display = state ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

Comment: Sure, but how would this fix the problem?

Comment: The code "should" work... I would need to see HTML to make sure it works.

Comment: Then this was a comment, not an answer.